# how to extract certain text from string

Tags: vb.net, string, pdf, for-loop, contains

How do I filter/extract strings?

I have converted a PDF file into String using itextsharp and I have the text displayed into a Richtextbox1.

However there are too many irrelevant text that I don't need in the Richtextbox.
Is there a way I can display the text I want based on keywords, the entire length of the text.

Example of text that is displayed in textrichbox1 after conversation of PDF to text:

```
**774**
**Bos00232940
Bos00320491
Das1234
Das3216**
RAGE*
```

So the keywords would be "**Bos**", "**Das**", "**774**".  and the new text that would be displayed in the richtextbox1 is shown below, instead of the entire text above.

```
*Bos00232940
Bos00320491
Das1234
Das3216
774*
```

Here is what I have so far. But it doesn't work it still displays the entire PDF in the richtextbox.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pdffilename As String
    pdffilename = TextBox1.Text
    Dim filepath = "c:\temp\" & TextBox1.Text & ".pdf"
    Dim thetext As String
    thetext = GetTextFromPDF(filepath)
    Dim lines() As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(thetext, Environment.NewLine)
    Dim keywords As New List(Of String)
    keywords.Add("Bos")
    keywords.Add("Das")
    keywords.Add("774")
    Dim newTextLines As New List(Of String)
    For Each line As String In lines
        For Each keyw As String In thetext

            If line.Contains(keyw) Then
                newTextLines.Add(line)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, newTextLines.ToArray)
End Sub
```

#### SOLUTION

Thanks everyone for your help. Below is the code that worked and did exactly what I wanted it to do.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pdffilename As String
    pdffilename = TextBox1.Text
    Dim filepath = "c:\temp\" & TextBox1.Text & ".pdf"
    Dim thetext As String
    thetext = GetTextFromPDF(filepath)

    Dim re As New Regex("[\t ](?<w>((774)|(Bos)|(Das))[a-z0-9]*)[\t ]", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)
    Dim Lines() As String = {thetext}
    Dim words As New List(Of String)
    For Each s As String In Lines
        Dim mc As MatchCollection = re.Matches(s)
        For Each m As Match In mc
            words.Add(m.Groups("w").Value)
        Next
    Next
    RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.ToArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I want to only display the text defined by the keywords I use. I don't want to display the entire PDF. and the keywords are not all in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to do it with regular expression...

```
    Dim re As New Regex("[\t ](?<w>((774)|(Bos)|(Das))[a-z0-9]*)[\t ]", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)

    Private Sub test()
        Dim Lines() As String = {"2 3 3 4 4 A A B B SHEET 1 OF 1 774 SIZE SCALE 24.000-47.999 12.000-23.999 CON BAG WIRE 90in. EX Bos00232940 Bos00320491 Das1234 Das3216 DETAILS 1 2 RAGE"}
        Dim words As New List(Of String)
        For Each s As String In Lines
            Dim mc As MatchCollection = re.Matches(s)
            For Each m As Match In mc
                words.Add(m.Groups("w").Value)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

Regex break down...

```
[\t ]     Single tab or space (there is an alternative for whitespace too)

(?<w>     Start of capture group called "w" This the the text returned later in the "m.Groups"

((774)|(Bos)|(Das))     one of the 3 blobs of text

[a-z0-9]*        any a-z or 0-9 character, * = any number of them

)         End of Capture group "w" from above.
```

Comment: With that specific regular expression, unless you need to know which line the item came from you don't even need to break up the document to multiple lines first. Can do the entire text blob in one Match Collection. I prefer to be able to debug the output more so this format works for me.

Comment: Your code worked fine, It got the job done, as to how it works I still have a lot to learn, I'm debugging it and stepping through the code to see how it works, maybe a little bit of code clean up is needed. but all I have to do now is just add some error handler, which I can do. thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each Word As String In thetext.Split(" ")
    For Each key As String In keywords
        If Word.StartsWith(key) Then
            newTextLines.Add(Word)
            Continue For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

or using LINQ:

```
Dim q = From word In thetext.Split(" ")
        Where keywords.Any(Function(s) word.StartsWith(s))
        Select word

RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, q.ToArray())
```

Comment: I think that's `Word` and not `Line` in `newTextLines.Add(Line)`

Answer (score 1):

If don't know the keywords in advance but know in which context they occur, you can find them with a Regex expression.  Two very handy Regex expressions allow you to find occurences succeeding or preceeding another:

`(?<=prefix)find` finds a pattern that follows another.

`find(?=suffix)` finds a pattern that comes before another.

If your number keyword (774) always preceeds " SIZE" you can find it like this: `\w+(?=\sSIZE)`.

If the other keywords are always between "EX " and " DETAILS" you can find them like this: `(?<=EX\s)(\w+\s)+(?=DETAILS)`.

You can put the whole thing together like this: `\w+(?=\sSIZE)|(?<=EX\s)(\w+\s)+(?=DETAILS)`.

The disadvantage is that the keywords between "EX " and "DETAILS" will be returned as one match. But you can split the matches afterwards as in:

```
Const input As String = "2 3 3 4 4 A A B B SHEET 1 OF 1 774 SIZE SCALE 24.000-47.999 12.000-23.999 CON BAG WIRE 90in. EX Bos00232940 Bos00320491 Das1234 Das3216 DETAILS 1 2 RAGE"

Dim matches = Regex.Matches(input, "\w+(?=\sSIZE)|(?<=EX\s)(\w+\s)+(?=DETAILS)")
For Each m As Match In matches
    Dim words = m.Value.Split(" "c)
    For Each word As String In words
        If word.Length > 0 Then ' Suppress the last empty word.
            Console.WriteLine(word)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Output:

> 774
>   Bos00232940
>   Bos00320491
>   Das1234
>   Das3216

Comment: "If the other keywords are always between "EX " and " DETAILS" you can find them like this: "

No, the keywords can appear randomly within the converted pdf file. so this would not work. however you gave me an idea, but like i said, its not consistent with the keywords